# Collator starts after more than 10 hours on Azure cloud

Tags: parachain-collator, block-production, blockchain, collator, block

I am migrating from AWS to Azure Cloud. I have two parachain collators running. One on AWS (yet to migrate) and another on Azure Cloud (migrated).
Whenever I restart the service on AWS, it hardly takes a couple of minutes to sync and start producing blocks. However, when I restart the service on Azure Cloud VM, the service takes more than 10 hours to start. No logs in debug mode. It just stops at `Is collating: yes` and nothing after that for a very long time.

Both the servers have 2-core CPUs and 8 GB of RAM.